# Angular Form отменить submit при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: html, angularjs, form, submit

Всем привет! Возможно, этот вопрос уже тут присутствует, но я, после поисков, ничего не нашла. Вопрос в следующем:

Имеется форма *editWordForm*, для одного из полей (*descLingv*) необходима "подсказка" - можно ввести текст вручную или выбрать текст из перечня уже существующих текстов. Тексты запрашиваются из базы.

Есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую открывается модальное окно (функция *getlastwords(type)*). В нем отображается список существующих текстов с возможностью фильтрации - при нажатии на нужный текст значение должно записываться в *wordDetails.DescLingvText*.

Однако при нажатии на кнопку помимо прописанной функции *getlastwords(type)* вызывается функция *saveWord*, которая прописана в атрибуте *ng-submit* формы.

Как "отменить" событие submit или исключить кнопку из формы?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate angular-validator name="editWordForm" ng-submit="saveWord()">
    <label class="control-label">Дескриптор</label>
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="lastWords" ng-click="getlastwords(1)">
        Выбрать текст
    </button>   
    <input class="form-control" name="descLingv" type="text" ng-model="wordDetails.DescLingvText">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="submit" value="Сохранить изменения"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте атрибут `type="button"` в вашу кнопку

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="lastWords" ng-click="getlastwords(1)">
```

По умолчанию тип для кнопки устанавливается в `submit` таким образом при клике и происходила отправка формы.